# error creating nbt file that includes nbt.tag.List file

Tags: python, minecraft

I am creating a nbt file whose root has two tags:

- DataVersion. It must be a tag_Int.
- size. You must set a tag_List of 3 tag_ints.

I did a few tests and determined that an error occurs when I try to pass a tag_List to the file.

This is my code:

```
import nbtlib as nbt

class Structure(nbt.File):
    def __init__(Self, data_version, size):
        #super().__init__({"DataVersion":nbt.Int(data_version), "size":nbt.List(map(nbt.Int, size))})
        super().__init__({"DataVersion":nbt.Int(data_version), "size":nbt.List(map(nbt.Int, size))})


structure = Structure(data_version=1952, size=(0, 0, 0))
structure.save("prueba.nbt")
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\studios dante 2\MODULES\Games\structurenbt\module.py", line 10, in <module>
    structure.save("prueba.nbt")
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nbtlib\nbt.py", line 132, in save
    self.write(buff, byteorder or self.byteorder)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nbtlib\tag.py", line 420, in write
    tag.write(buff, byteorder)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nbtlib\tag.py", line 365, in write
    write_numeric(BYTE, self.subtype.tag_id, buff, byteorder)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\nbtlib\tag.py", line 84, in write_numeric
    buff.write(fmt[byteorder].pack(value))
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Can someone help me to fix the problem? I use python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it, turns out I had the nbtlib out of date. I updated it and it works!